# Login error Page using PHP page

Tags: php, html, session

i have login page if my username and password is incorrect it will display the error message using different page. i am using separate page for that. how can i display error message in login page itself.

### login

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN”>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title> PHP Login </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <center>
 <form method=”post” action=”login.php”>
 <table>
 <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type=”text” name=”usr”></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type=”password” name=”pswd”></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type=”submit” name=”login” value=”Login”></td>
 <td><input type=”reset” name=”reset” value=”Reset”></td></tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 </center>
 </body>
  </html>
```

### Controller

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_REQUEST['usr']==”ABC” && $_REQUEST['pswd']==”123″){
$_SESSION['usr'] = “ABC”;
$_SESSION['pswd'] = “123″;
header(“Location: content.php”);
}
else{
header(“Location: niceform.php”);
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! May I refer you to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This website is for asking for ***help*** with your already made code, not just asking for code to be written for you.

Comment: For one thing, these => `“ ”` won't work and fill fail miserably. You need to replace all of those with `"` (standard double quotes).

Answer (score 1):

### Your code contained invalid double-quotes.

I replaced all instances of `“` and `”` with `"` (standard double-quotes).

#### The cause is usually the result from copying/pasting code taken from the Web.

## See reformatted code below.

---

**To show an error message in login page**, you can use any of the following:

Replace `header("Location: niceform.php");` with `echo "Sorry, no access;"`

or with `die("Sorry, no access");` or `exit("Sorry, no access");`

**Sidenote**:

You can use `include 'content.php';` to include a file instead of redirecting with `header()`

---

### This code has been tested and working.

**HTML Form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Login </title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<table>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="usr"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pswd"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_REQUEST['usr']=="ABC" && $_REQUEST['pswd']=="123"){
$_SESSION['usr'] = "ABC";
$_SESSION['pswd'] = "123";
header("Location: content.php");
// include 'content.php'; // optional, but delete the line above if using it.
}
else{
header("Location: niceform.php");
// include 'niceform.php'; // optional, but delete the line above if using it.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this way

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if($_REQUEST['usr']==”ABC” && $_REQUEST['pswd']==”123″){
   $_SESSION['usr'] = “ABC”;
   $_SESSION['pswd'] = “123″;
   header(“Location: content.php”);
}
else{
    header(“Location: niceform.php”);
}
```